# Excel VBA Cell referencing after autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 batches of autofilters that work just fine. After the filter, i need to know how can i reference a cell (in this case the very first cell in Column D) as this particular column is common across all rows once filtered.

how can i reference this and assign this value to variable xCellD?

```
Dim xcount As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim xCellD As String


Set ws1 = Sheets("Main")


On Error Resume Next

'ProjectID
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value

'City
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value

'Location Type
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Test"

xcellD = the very first cell in Column D
```

Comment: Note: Never use `On Error Resume Next` without error handling. This line just hides **all** error messages of all following lines but the errors still occur. You cannot debug or fix errors in code with using that line. Remove it or implement a error handling instead.

Comment: Hi Peh, i do have erro handling in the bottom part of the code. it is just not that relevant as i only need to reference the cell after an autofilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value by …

1. `Resize` and `Offset` column D to exclude the header.
2. Use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get all visible cells
3. Access the first visible cell

Eg use

```
xcellD = Columns("D").Resize(Columns("D").Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Value
```

Comment: Thanks Peh. I would have to research how Resize works. thank you so much.

Comment: `.Resize(Columns("D").Rows.Count - 1)` resizes the row size of the column D by `-1` (so it actually removes the last 1 row of the selection) and then we use `Offset(1)` to move the selection one row down (so actually the first row is not selected but row 2 up to the last row). Finally `SpecialCells` selects the visible cells of that selection and `.Cells(1)` selects the first cell of that.